# Как сделать что бы после функции сразу должна была быть другая функция? По типу хендлер в telebot

Tags: python, библиотеки

Я создаю библиотеку для написание telegram ботов и я столкнулся с проблемой хендлеров, я хочу сделать их
как в telebot но не знаю как сделать что бы после функции стояла другая функция которую хендлер запускал вот так:
bot.message_handler():
def function():
pass
Как это можно реализовать?
Я пробовал просто передавать функцию в хендлер но это не работает.

Comment: Это называется [декораторы](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/decorators-in-python/)